# How to serialize a form using jquery .serialize() method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My Form is:

```
<form class="something" id="main-form">
 -----content----
```

My Jquery is:

```
 $("form :input").change(function() {
var data = $('#main-form').serialize();
console.log(data);


$.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo  Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('jobs/index'); ?>",
        //dataType:"json",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#main-form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

But the form is not serialized.The data field is coming empty.Please help.

Comment: Show your `console.log()` data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [.serialize();](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) :

> the element must have a name attribute.

So make sure you give all inputs a `name='whatever'`.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CWJDj/1/

Answer (score 1):

See if this works any better:

```
var data = $('#main-form').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var data = $("form#main-form").serialize();
```

That's Done.